# Codewars problem 'Happy numbers' how can i make some changes on my code to make it works?

Tags: javascript

I am working Codewars problem' Happy Numbers ' here is the link https://www.codewars.com/kata/happy-numbers-5/train/javascript Here is the problem, when I am running the code when n > 98 the maximum call stack size is reached. How can I make some changes on my code to fix this problem?

```
function happyNumbers(x){
  var res = [];
  for (let i = 1; i <= x; i++){
    var str = [];
    if (helper(str,i)){res.push(i)}
  }
  return res
}

function helper(str,n){
  var num = 0;
  if (n === 1){return true}
  if (str.indexOf(n) > -1){return false}
  str.push(n);
  if (n.toString().length === 1){num = Math.pow(n,2).toString()}
  if (n.toString().length >= 2){
    num = n.toString().split('')
    .reduce((a,b) => Math.pow(a,2)+ Math.pow(b,2)).toString();
  }
  return helper(str,Number(num))
}
```

Comment: Count the number of `helper` calls and exit if it's above 100 or so. (because in that case the algorithm has entered an infinite loop)

Comment: My take: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/4cu1zms6/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe some more simplyfing would help by

- using a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) for visited value to prevent circular loop which never ends ([Memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization)),
- taking numerical values at all, only for splitting into single digits, a string is taken,
- summing up by using a simple multiplication,
- now some exit function:

  - check if `sum` is `1`, exit the function with `true`,
  - check if `sum` is already visited and if so, exit with `false`,
- return by calling the function again with `sum` and updated set `visited` with `sum`.

```js
function happyNumbers(x, visited = new Set) {
    var sum = 0, value;
    for (value of String(x)) sum += value * value;
    if (sum === 1) return true;
    if (visited.has(sum)) return false;
    return happyNumbers(sum, visited.add(sum));
}

console.log(happyNumbers(123));
```

Comment: how would you answer this type of question?

Comment: I would describe possible improvements in plain english, including some small snippets, leaving the solution as a whole to the OP. Eg "Your `helper` function is pure, which means that it will always return the same values for the same input. Therefore you could [memoize] the function, which will greatly reduce the number of calculations (and recursive calls) the function has to do. A `Set` could be used to store the visited ones."